# Cannot update WP post title and slug via SQL

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I try to replace 2023 to 2024 in WordPress post_title and post_name(slug), as below:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts`
SET post_title = REPLACE(post_title, '(2023)', '(2024)'), post_name = REPLACE(post_name, '-2023', '-2024')
WHERE (post_title LIKE '%(2023)%') and (post_type = 'post');
```

However, after executing the query, although the data in the table are changed, in WP Dashboard, the title and slug of the post are not. Why?

I have tried to clear the cache but do not work.

Update:

Finally I use WP Migrate's find & replace feature to replace all "(2023)" to "(2024)" in all wp tables, and it works.

Comment: @ITgoldman, I want to perform a more accurate match, sometimes, the title or name may contains string like "SQL Server 2024", which should not be replaced. We only want to replace those containing like "11 Best Outlook PST Repair Tools (2023)" and slug with "-2023" in post https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/11-best-outlook-pst-repair-tools-2023/

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_title = REPLACE(post_title, '2024', '2025'),post_name = REPLACE(post_name, '2024', '2025') WHERE post_type = 'post' AND (post_title LIKE '%2024%' OR post_name LIKE '%2024%');
```

This query should replace all occurrences of '2023' with '2024' in both the post_title and post_name columns for posts with the post type 'post'. The % in the LIKE condition allows for matching '2023' anywhere in the title or slug.

I recommend utilizing the global $wpdb object with `$wpdb->posts` instead of directly referencing `wp_posts`

Answer (score 0):

If you have not disabled revisions in WordPress you must also include the "revision" post_type in the query:

```
... AND ( post_type = 'post' OR post_type = 'revision' );
```

Comment: Sorry but why? I cannot understand, since I only need to update post, not the revisions.

Comment: Maybe you are correct. I use WP Migrate to replace all (2023) to (2024) in all tables and it works.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).